# How can I get values with discriminited union type from recursive function

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I am trying to obtain a specific value from one list with a multiple recursion so I have :

```
    type PowerSystem =
      | System of string * int
      | Junction of string * List<PowerSystem>
    
    let Starship =
      Junction("Core", 
        [ 
          Junction("Users",
                [
                System("Main Computer",-10);
                System("Library Computer",-10);
                Junction("Defence",)]
 let rec JunctionPath (pSystem:PowerSystem) =
    match pSystem with
    | Junction(name,aList) ->  SplitList2 aList
    | System(name,aNumber) ->   [name]

 
  
and SplitList2 list =
    match list with 
    | [] -> printfn "%A" []
    | head::tail -> printfn "%A" List.filter (fun e->e="Port Phasers" (JunctionPath head)@(SplitList2 tail))

JunctionPath Starship
```

I get error FS0001: The type ''a -> string list' does not match the type 'unit'

I want to get the name of junctions when the system is called Main Computer but I can't call other functions. I tryed in different ways to get those values but I can't found the way. Thanks in advance

Comment: btw you missed a closing square bracket in `let Startship = ...`

Answer (score 0):

`SplitList2` only has the side effect of `printfn` hence returns unit `()`.

In `JunctionPath` the first branch returns a list of string -  `[name]` - and the second a `unit` due to calling `SplitList2`. This is not allowed as both (in general all) pattern match branches should return the same type. This is why you get your error "error FS0001: The type ''a -> string list' does not match the type 'unit'"
(It would be clearer if you, in future, note the line references in the error as that points to the problematic line).

Now in answer to your last point:

> I want to get the name of junctions when the system is called Main
> Computer but I can't call other functions. I tryed in different ways
> to get those values but I can't found the way.

this does not make sense since what is *"Port Phasers"*? Anyway, without testing, I have modified SplitList2 to return a list on either branch. Then we pipe the result of `JunctionPath` into a printfn. However the logic of the line `List.filter (fun e->e="Port Phasers" (JunctionPath head)@(SplitList2 tail))` still does not make sense, so I updated it as I think you meant it (although you should have had another error for this?). (This is not tail recursive and can be improved but one step at a time)

```
  type PowerSystem =
      | System of string * int
      | Junction of string * List<PowerSystem>
    
    let Starship =
      Junction("Core", 
        [ 
          Junction("Users",
                [
                System("Main Computer",-10);
                System("Library Computer",-10);
                Junction("Defence",)]
 let rec JunctionPath (pSystem:PowerSystem) =
    match pSystem with
    | Junction(name,aList) ->  SplitList2 aList
    | System(name,aNumber) ->   [name]

 and SplitList2 list =
    match list with 
    | [] ->  []
    | head::tail -> List.filter (fun e->e="Port Phasers") (JunctionPath head)@(SplitList2 tail))

JunctionPath Starship |> printfn "%A%
```